# ng-click não é acionado dentro de uma <label> (Angular1)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Boa tarde,

No meu projeto, tenho uma componente que é partilhada por outras componentes diferentes. Essa componente chama-se toggle-switch-input. Esta componente serve para permitir o filtro de alguns valores de uma lista, e cada item tem um *slider* que, após o seu clique, deverá ocorrer um efeito em slide. No seu html (toggle-switch-input.html), tenho o seguinte código:

```html
<label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    ng-click="vm.itemToggleSwitch(vm.choices.indexOf(choice))"
    ng-checked="!vm.isSelected(vm.choices.indexOf(choice))">
    
    <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```

E no seu controlador (toggle-switch-input.controller.js) tenho as respetivas funções (***isSelected*** e ***itemToggleSwitch***). Existem muitas páginas que utilizam esta componente sem qualquer problema, à excepção de uma delas. Estive a fazer alguns prints na consola do *browser* e, quando clico no elemento que pretendo (neste caso num botão em formato *slide*), ele chama a função isSelected, mas por algum motivo não consegue chamar a função do *ng-click* (itemToggleSwitch). No entanto, nas outras páginas isto ocorre sem qualquer tipo de problema: Ele faz o slide, chamando as funções isSelected e itemToggleSwitch.

Alguém tem alguma luz? Estou à volta do código e não estou a ver nenhuma solução possível. O mais estranho é que esta componente consegue ser partilhada perfeitamente por outras componentes, menos numa.

As duas funções presentes no controlador toggle-switch-input.controller.js:

```js
this.isSelected = (index) => {
  if(this.ngModel.$modelValue.indexOf(this.choices[index]) === -1){
    return false;
  } else{
    return true;
  }
};

this.itemToggleSwitch = function (index) {

    var newList = angular.copy(this.ngModel.$modelValue);

    var itemIndex = newList.indexOf(this.choices[index]);

    if(itemIndex === -1){
        newList.push(this.choices[index]);
    } else {
        newList.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    }

    this.ngModel.$setViewValue(newList);
}.bind(this);
```

Muito obrigado e continuação de um bom dia!

Comment: Realmente estranho. Você consegue colocar os 2 HTML, um de uma página que está funcionando e o HTML da página que não está funcionando na Pergunta para compararmos? Obrigado

Comment: Poder posso, mas por exemplo, vamos comparar o .html de uma página que funciona de outra que não funciona: ambas têm o seguinte trecho de código nas suas páginas: <filter-column> ............ </filter-column>. Esse filter-column chamará então este <toggle-switch-input>. Os parâmetros que passo no filter-column são os mesmos nos dois html. Daí ser muito estranho..